# Adding custom claim to ID token OpenID

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, openid

I am on .NET Core 3.1 and I am trying to add a custom claim to a JWT token but I am unable to do so. If you look at the code below, I am able to read the custom token using this line of Code

`User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "role")`

But when I grab the JWT token and put it in JWT.ms, the new custom claim is not present in the token. `.OnTokenValidated` is the event where I attempted to add the custom claim to the token before it is returned by the idp.

```
AddOpenIdConnect("test",o => {
               o.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
               o.SignOutScheme = "Cookies";
               o.ClientId = "f";
               o.ClientSecret = "0e";
               o.Authority = "https://test.com";
               o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
               o.MetadataAddress = "https://test.com/.well-known/openid-configuration";
              
              
               **o.Events.OnTokenValidated = async (ctx) =>
               {
                   var claimsIdentity = ctx.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                   claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "Admin"));
               };**
             
               o.SaveTokens = true;
               o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, some fundamentals:

- AddOpenIdConnect that you use in the client never modify any tokens.
- Tokens are never modified after they are issued.

when you use this code:

```
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "Admin"));
```

You are adding it to the User (ClaimsPrincipal) that was created from the ID-Token. This claim is then typically saved in the local session cookie. So this line never modifies any tokens.

Perhaps you can try to add that claim in the authorization service?

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/) and [Exploring what is inside the ASP.NET Core cookies](https://Exploring%20what%20is%20inside%20the%20ASP.NET%20Core%20cookies.)

Comment: So how can I add a claim for a JWT token that will be used for API calls as a part of the header(Bearer Basic Auth header)? - referenced link does not help here, I need to have it in as a part of the token not in the cookie.

Comment: you can't modify the tokens in the client, as they are signed by the authorization server. If want to to inject custom claims in the client (ClamsPrincipal) user, then there is a set of event hocks that you can hook into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-7.0